# My nokia lumia says my password is wrong but it isnt

Tags: lumia, password

My nokia lumia is saying that my password is incorrect and has made me wait for up to 550 minutes now. The password i constantly type in is the correct one as I had been using it a few moments before. How do I fix it so I can use it again? (Preferably a method that means I dont loose anything on my phone)

Comment: This question is not the same as the other question is saying that they entered the wrong password, however, I am saying that I entered the correct password but my phone says that it is wrong.